# API gateway works with only publicly open EC2

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gateway

I have created a HelloWorld SpringBoot app and deployed it on a EC2 instance. I can invoke it through my HTTP browser with `http://<My EC2 instance IPv4 address>/tax` after I add the following inbound rules

```
CustomTCP TCP 8080 <my laptop Ip>
SSH       TCP 22   <my laptop Ip>
```

I went ahead to create a API Gateway with GET method with Integration Type as HTTP and with the above URL. But when I test the GET method, I get

`"message": "Network error communicating with endpoint"`.

I tried giving various inbound rules but no success. Finally after creating a open inbound rule of All Traffic for everyone the API worked fine.

Clearly I cannot go ahead with this open inbound rule, what specific inbound rule should I create for my API to work? What IP should I use in the inbound rule? Does API even have an IP?

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, your application needs to be publicly accessible to be used by API Gateway.

However, you can use SSL certificates to restrict access to your HTTP backend only to API Gateway. [This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html) shows how to do that.

See [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=204629) for a related discussion on AWS forum.